# Javascript: How to change datetime value during onChange event?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the value of an input box every time the user change the value of a dropdown. The value should be the "current date time" I can't make it work. With my code below, every time I changed a dropdown value of a specific row (let say in row 3), the value of the input box (Current Date Time) in all the rows were affected. They have the same current date time value. The other rows Current Date Time value should not be changed. Only the row where the user changed the dropdown. Am I missing something here? I have to use DOM by the way.

```
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Value to Select: <select onChange="changeDateTime();"></select></td>
        <td>Current Date Time: <input/></td>

      </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeDateTime(){

  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var currentDateTime = date+' '+time;

  var d =  id('myTable', document); 
  for (var x=1; x<d.rows.length; x++) {                    
       d.rows[x].cells[2].firstChild.value = currentDateTime;
       } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below snippet.

```js
function changeDateTime(obj) {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var currentDateTime = date + ' ' + time;

  var _input = obj.parentNode.nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
  _input.value = currentDateTime;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Value to Select:
      <select onChange="changeDateTime(this);">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>Current Date Time:
      <input/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value to Select:
      <select onChange="changeDateTime(this);">
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>Current Date Time:
      <input />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that look wrong here is you should start with 0 index

```
for (var x=0; x<d.rows.length; x++) {                    
   d.rows[x].cells[2].firstChild.value = currentDateTime;
}
```

Comment: How can I check if a value on the select dropdown changed?

Comment: you have already written this callback <select onChange="changeDateTime();"></select> ........... so changeDateTime function will be only called after selection is changed

Answer (score 0):

I have done some change in your HTML to put some data on your select list. See below:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Value to Select: <select onchange="javascript:changeDateTime();">
      <option>-- select --</option><option>ShowDate</option>

    </select></td>
    <td>Current Date Time: <input id="txtDate"/></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, did some changes in javascript function, which is showing datetime in textbox by getting text box by id.

```
function changeDateTime(){
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" +   today.getSeconds();
  var currentDateTime = date+' '+time;
  document.getElementById('txtDate').value = currentDateTime;  
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxaumjz0/)

Hope it works for you !!

Answer (score 0):

Remember Arrays start at 0 so your script should look like this

```
var d = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var x=0; x<d.rows.length; x++) {
  d.rows[x].cells[1].lastChild.value = currentDateTime;
}
```

also the input field isn't the `firstChild`.

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/jemuhuloze/edit?html,js,output)

Note:

This way you change the Date in every row don't know if you want that.
If not I would use [Pugazh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37205820/5183019) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using firstChild, what you really need is [firstElementChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_firstelementchild.asp) property. 
There are several [types of nodes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp) available, and what you are looking for is a node of type Element.

The reason your code doesn't work (besides that array indexes should start from 0, so `x=0` and  `cell[1]`) is that actually a firstChild is a node of type text, and not the input element node. Do **not** use lastChild either, because you don't know if there is gonna be an empty text node.

There could be an easyer way by setting a class attribute to the input tag, so you can use getElementsByClassName() function.

If you still want to go that way, here is the solution.
Correct this for loop and you are fine.

```
for (var x=0; x<d.rows.length; x++) {
            d.rows[x].cells[1].firstElementChild.value = currentDateTime;
}
```